# How can I filter an optional model inside include in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, foreign-keys, .net-7.0

I'm using .NET 7 and i have the following model class:

```
public class MachineSchedule : BaseModel
    {
        public int MachineScheduleId { get; set; }
        public EWeekDay WeekDay { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan InitialProductionTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan FinalProductionTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        #region Relationships

        public virtual ICollection<MachineOperation>? MachineOperations { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Shift>? Shifts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ScheduledStop>? ScheduledStops { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

And i want to make a query filtering, for example, the "Shift" model class, so i have:

```
machineScheduleDto = _context
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Include(m => m.Shifts.Where(s => s.Type == shiftType));
```

But since my relationship is optional, i receive the following warning:

> Possible null reference argument for parameter.

How can i solve this? I know that if i add "required" in the declaration of the class, all of the problems are solved, but my relationship is really optional, so add this seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the null-forgiving operator (!):

```
machineScheduleDto = _context
     .AsNoTracking()
     .Include(m => m.Shifts!.Where(s => s.Type == shiftType));
```

...and I wonder if it will go faster the code:

```
machineScheduleDto = _context.Shifts!
     .AsNoTracking()
     .Where(s => s.Type == shiftType)
     .Include(c => c.MachineSchedule)
     .Select(c => c.MachineSchedule);
```